# Dynamic Layout : few lines, great issues with generateViewId()

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, view

I'm a relatively new to programming and I'm trying to create an App in Android Studio that uses a dynamic layout. Of course I will need the created Views to be assigned an ID so that I can read and display specific data via the findViewbyId method. However the generateViewId() method seems to fail here. I've broken my code down to an easy example for better illustration:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MultiAutoCompleteTextView mactv;
ArrayList<Integer> id_List = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamicLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mactv = new MultiAutoCompleteTextView(MainActivity.this);
        mactv.setLayoutParams(params);
        mactv.generateViewId();
        mactv.setHint("This is Number: " + i);
        layout.addView(mactv);
        id_List.add(mactv.getId());
    }
    Log.e("Path 1",id_List.toString());

}}
```

Here's the layout xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="test.dynamiclayout.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dynamicLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I run this code, Logcat will show the ViewIds as [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1] and this certainly is the reason I'm having trouble with my actual code. I'm just puzzled as to what I did wrong here? I thought these few lines would be a straight forward thing...

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) `generateViewId` does this:

> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int)

As this value isn't set automatically you'll need to assign this value using `mactv.setId(mactv.generateViewId)`.

Comment: This works! I didn't even think of that :P Thanks so much!